# How to read details of the X.509 certificate stored on usb token?

Tags: c++, x509certificate, pkcs#11

I am using SafeNet's iKey usb token for my application.

My application is in C++ (win32 app) and I am accessing token's functionality through PKCS interface (pkcs11.h) from its SDK.

So far, I've been able to successfully do the following: generate public/private key pair, encrypt/decrypt, sign/verify, read attributes of objects stored inside the token.

But the main problem is: after importing X.509 certificate into the token (using iKey Token Utility), I can't read certificate details in my C++ application, as I need these to know which user is using my application, i.e user identity. However, with the "iKey Token Utility", which comes with the token driver, it is possible to view the certificate details. I couldn't find source code of that utility anywhere, also pkcs11.h library doesn't have any functions related to reading certificate details. For me, it would be just helpful to read public key value (not its handle) of the certificate.

I tried to read attributes of the certificate object inside the token using PKCS, but seems it gives me values encoded in some format.

I thoroughly looked through the SDK documentation, and over the Internet, but I couldn't find answer to my question:

- How to read X509 certificate details from usb security token using PKCS in C++?

I would appreciate any hints to solve this problem, thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the PKCS#11, X509 certificates are some kind of stored objects that their data class (`CKA_CLASS` attribute) equals to `CKO_CERTIFICATE`.
If you want to retrieve a certificate object from your token, all you need is to use `C_GetAttributeValue` function.
Before doing this you may want find all x.509 certificates stored on your token:

```
CK_BBOOL _true = CK_TRUE;
CK_OBJECT_CLASS certClass = CKO_CERTIFICATE;
CK_CERTIFICATE_TYPE certType = CKC_X_509_ATTR_CERT;
CK_ATTRIBUTE certificateSearchTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_CLASS, &certClass, sizeof(dataClass)},
    {CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, &certType, sizeof(certType)},
    {CKA_TOKEN, &_true, sizeof(_true)}
};

CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject;
CK_ULONG ulObjectCount;
CK_RV rv = C_FindObjectsInit(hSession, certificateSearchTemplate, 3);
assert(rv == CKR_OK);
while (1) {
   rv = C_FindObjects(hSession, &hObject, 1, &ulObjectCount);
   if (rv != CKR_OK || ulObjectCount == 0)
      break;
   //hObject is handle of a x.509 certificate, so you can fetch your desired attributes from it using C_GetAttributeValue
  getCertificateAttributes(hObject);
}
rv = C_FindObjectsFinal(hSession);
assert(rv == CKR_OK);
```

and in `getCertificateAttributes` function you can get desired certificate attributes:

```
void getCertificateAttributes(CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hCert)
{
   CK_ATTRIBUTE pTemplate[] = {
      //List your desired attributes here
   };
   ...
   CK_RV rv = C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, hCert, &pTemplate, pTemplateLen);
   if (rv == CKR_OK) {
      //here you have your desired certificate attributes
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ehsan. Theoretically, this should be the correct method. As I mentioned, I tried reading all attributes of the certificate, but it didn't give me the values I need. For example, it doesn't have the attribute holding the pub. key, but it has CKA_LABEL attribute, whose value is ok. My problem would be solved if I could extract the pub. key value.

Comment: In my case, CKA_VALUE attribute holds the largest data, over 800 bytes, but it is unrecognizable as certificate details, I guess certificate details(including the pub. key) are stored in these bytes in some encoding, in that case the problem remains in how to decode these bytes...

Comment: Are you sure that the certificate is stored on your token correctly?
How did you stored it on your token?
For more details about X.509 certificate object attributes you can refer to table 24 in PKCS#11 specs: ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-11/v2-30/pkcs-11v2-30b-d6.pdf

Comment: Yes, the certificate is definitely stored correctly on the token, because it is possible to view cert. info with the utility program from the vendor. I think the attribute values are stored in DER encoding, and they should be converted from DER to human-readable form.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from PKCS#11 library, **Microsoft CryptoAPI**(mscapi.dll) can also be used for retrieving certificate details. However, **MSCAPI** also uses **PKCS** internally to interact with the usb token. So, there should be some way to solve the problem using PKCS library alone and without MSCAPI.